# What would the cosmic microwave background radiation look like in a hyperspherical universe?

Tags: cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

I was thinking about what things would look like in a hyperspherical universe. How would galaxies look as they got closer to the other side of that hypersphere?  It seems like if a galaxy were on the other side of that hypersphere, light from that galaxy would come from every direction, and it's image would be smear across the entire sky.

So then I was thinking what if the size of the universe was small enough that the light that forms the CMB traveled from locations closer to the other side of the universe than this side.  That light would also be smeared, and so be more uniform than we might expect if we thought we lived in a flat universe.

And this would then have an impact on how fast inflation would have to happen in order to account for that uniformity.

I can't be the first one to think of this, but I've never come across an article that's addressed this.

So first question:  Does this idea track?
Second: Has anyone come across a reference that explores this idea?

---

[What would we see if we lived on a hypersphere?][1]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiGe2x8t6mA

Comment: There is a great deal of information in the CMB. Don Lincoln of FermiLab has made a few videos on it. [Secrets of the Cosmic Microwave Background](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ri2LIEjXhmE). PBS SpaceTime has some too.

Comment: There were some studies a few decades ago that searched for repetition in galaxy patterns consistent with a universe of positive curvature (and sufficiently small circumference), but they found no evidence. There's been much less motivation for such searches since the discovery of accelerating expansion.